# Can I put a script tag inside a table?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently in college taking a webdesign class and we are working with javascript. We have an assignment to create a table that gives us random numbers inside using `<script>` and `<table>`. My question is where to put the  tag?

I've tried using quotes around the `<td>` tags but it still isn't loading on my site.

```
<body>
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <script>
    '<td></td>'
    '<td>d</td>'
    '<td>d</td>'
</script>
```

The table I'm supposed to be making has 3 columns and 10 rows with 10 random variables from 50-100 in one column.

edit: Here is exactly what I have to do for the assignment:

All the numbers are random
Create code to make a table with a border
inside  the table
    •   create at least 1 function to call 10 random variables from 50-100
    •   use if/else statements
    •   post a pic how you feel about each letter grade
outside the table
    •   average the total score for all 10 grades and tell me the average score

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding script and javascripts role in a web page

Comment: You should create 2 loops, 1 for columns and one for rows and generate everything with javascript

Comment: to answer the question in the title, according to documentation, permitted parents of `<script>` are *Any element that accepts [metadata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Metadata_content) content, or any element that accepts [phrasing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) content.* so, no you can't put a script there anyway - and `script` content is javascript, not random text

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AdrianBrand To make a table and be able to get random numbers in each cell everytime I reload the page

Comment: Then use a querySelector to select all the table cells and add a random number in it.That is a starter to look into.

Comment: @AdrianBrand What? I don't want anyone to write my homework for me. Sorry if it came across like that. I'm new to this and want to know where I'm making a mistake.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody id="mybody"></tbody>

        </table>

        <script>
            // script after element rendered on page
            let b = document.getElementById('mybody');
            let tr = '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + parseInt( Math.random()  * 1000) + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + parseInt( Math.random()  * 100) + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + parseInt( Math.random()  * 10) + '</td>' +
                '</tr>';

            b.innerHTML = tr;   // add content to body of table

        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is it a best practice to generate content in JS? I figured it was best to just change the content of already existing tags as opposed to drawing them out of thin air to aid in tracking down bugs. Am I wrong or is it fine to do it this way?

Comment: Don't use document.write